# Show that $f\left(\lambda \right)=\lambda $ .

Tags: calculus, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous function and sequence $x_n$ defined as:
$x_1=a,$    $a\in \mathbb{R}$
$x_{n+1}\:=\:f\left(x_n\right)$.

Also, $\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(x_n\right)\:=\:\lambda ,\:\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.
Show that $$f\left(\lambda \right)=\lambda $$ .

So far, i know that from *Heine Theorem*, $\lim _{n\to \infty }f\left(x_n\right)\:=\:f\left(\lambda \right)$. I thought about show that also $f\left(x_n\right)\rightarrow \lambda $ and then from the uniqueness of limits i'll get that $f\left(\lambda \right)\:=\:\lambda $. But how to do that? any ideas? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there.

From the theorem you quoted, it is correct that $f(x_n) \to f(\lambda)$.

You wanted to show $f(x_n) \to \lambda$ and then use the uniqueness of limits. This is a good approach.

Hint: Use that $f(x_n) = x_{n+1}$ and then $\lim f(x_n) = \lim ...$

Comment: I can say this? i wasn't sure because $x_n$ is defined in recursive way.

Comment: It *is* defined in a recursive way. But it does not matter :)

Comment: The point here is that you have some sequence $x_n$ that converges to $\lambda$, and - never mind the recursion - you know that there is a function $f$ that when applied to the sequence, simply shifts the sequence to the left by one (i.e. $x_1, x_2, x_3\ldots$ becomes $x_2, x_3, x_4 \ldots$). Then of course $f(x_n)$ also converges to $\lambda$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that by hypothesis you have $f(x_n) = x_{n+1} \to \lambda$, and so you are done.